How can I accurately calculate the macros (protein, fat, carbs) for homemade skyr, especially considering the whey that gets drained off?
I'm making homemade skyr using skim milk and a small amount of Siggi's skyr as a starter. After culturing and straining for 4-8 hours, much of the whey is drained off. Since the whey contains proteins and carbs, I’m unsure how to account for the macros in the final product.
Is there a reliable method to estimate the nutritional values after straining, or should I be adjusting based on the amount of whey lost?

Lacking an actual lab analysis it's usually most on track to guess that it will be similar to a commercial labeled product made similarly. And not to expect "precise" at all.
